# Modifying Twisted's FileSender() to support byte range headers

Tags: python, http-headers, twisted, twisted.web

I'm using twisted as part of my video streaming application, HTML5 video streaming relies heavily on byte-range for scrubbing... but FileSender doesn't seem to support byte-range (leading to a few problems).

Previously I was just passing everything through to Static.File.render_GET, which must have supported byte-ranges but due to a few changes since then that's no longer viable.

```
request.setHeader('Content-Type','video/octet-stream')
print request.getAllHeaders()
self.isLeaf = False
#return static.File.render_GET(self,request)
f = open('.path/to/file.mp4','rb')

def cbFinished(ignored):
    f.close()
    request.finish()

d = FileSender().beginFileTransfer(f,request)
d.addErrback(err).addCallback(cbFinished)
return NOT_DONE_YET
```

The code that gets passed a request if the requested filetype is 'mp4', and I've been getting errors like:

```
<GET /file.mp4 HTTP/1.1>
{'range': 'bytes=66673263716-', 'host': '192.168.1.64:8000', 'accept': '*/*', 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Nintendo WiiU) AppleWebKit/534.52 (KHTML, like Gecko) NX/2.1.0.8.23 NintendoBrowser/1.1.0.7579.EU'}
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: exceptions.Exception: Consumer asked us to stop producing
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: exceptions.RuntimeError: Producer was not unregistered for file.mp4
<GET /file.mp4 HTTP/1.1>
{'range': 'bytes=69839914264-', 'host': '192.168.1.64:8000', 'accept': '*/*', 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Nintendo WiiU) AppleWebKit/534.52 (KHTML, like Gecko) NX/2.1.0.8.23 NintendoBrowser/1.1.0.7579.EU'}
```

Which shows that the WiiU is requesting different byte-ranges, leading me to think that that's the problem.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why is it "no longer viable"?

Comment: I think Static.File gets set up with a path and expects every request to be relative to the path it was set up with, and since I need to serve files that could be anywhere I figured Static.File wouldn't work well.

Comment: That sounds confusing, and in any event incorrect, which I guess you figured out from your answer :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, turns out `static.File` was precisely what I was looking for.
I'd convinced myself that it only worked when set up as a directory, but it works fine as a single file.
code is now:

```
rangedFile = static.File('/path/to/file.mp4',
                         defaultType='video/octet-stream')
return rangedFile.render_GET(request)
```